# How do I identify make / model of this kitchen faucet?

Tags: kitchens, bathroom-fixtures

I am trying to identify this fixture, to get some rebuild parts: [image: bathroom fixture]

What approach should I use?

(It is a kitchen fixture in use in a bathroom)

Comment: unless you know that it's a high-end faucet, it's likely easier to just replace it.

Comment: Interesting point. We have two matching, and would prefer to avoid replacement, for multiple reasons.

Comment: That looks like a kitchen faucet.  If the handles are 8" on center, it's going to be considered a kitchen faucet.  That could help you look in the right area at least.

Comment: @JPhi1618  Yes, you are right. Forgot that aspect! OP enhanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an American Standard "Cadet" MODEL NUMBER: 6425
http://www.americanstandard-us.com/kitchen-faucets/Cadet-Two-Handle-Kitchen-Faucet-2197/